# Flink 1.15: Error setting BATCH execution mode for DataStream API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I am using Flink 1.15 DataStream api to do ETL job. I want to set my job set BATCH execution mode, so I use code provided in official webstie. `env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);`
However, I encountered the following error:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.ResultPartition.getAllDataProcessedFuture(ResultPartition.java:233)`

My whole code logic

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile("file:///path/to/file");

`env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);`

DataStream<OutputType> result = text
.map(/* map logic here */ )
.keyBy(/* keyby logic here */)
.reduce(/* reduce logic here */)

result.writeAsText("filePath")
```

Can anyone provide some insights on why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?
Thanks!

---

Background of my project (if you want to know more why I want to use batch mode):

I am currently working on a job that reads data from S3, performs some transformations and reductions on the data with keys.
In the process, I am encountering a problem where my application seems to store every intermediate reduction result rather than just the final reduced value for each key. I understand that this is likely due to the nature of streaming execution, which continuously processes events as they arrive.My situation is quite similar to this post : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828218/how-to-avoid-duplicate-key-tuples-in-word-count-w-apache-flink](https://stackoverflow.com)

So I want to change to batch mode to see if it works.

---

what I try:

1. I delete the transformation logic, but still have the same error as above:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile("file:///path/to/file");

`env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);`

text.writeAsText("filePath")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by disabling checkpoints. This is specific to running it in aws managed flink. In terraform I added this

```
flink_application_configuration {
      checkpoint_configuration {
        configuration_type    = "CUSTOM"
        checkpointing_enabled = false // disable checkpoints since it is a batch job
      }
```

Inside of the aws_kinesisanalyticsv2_application resource.